# Rails mixes global and local rake version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

Yesterday I updated to Ruby 3.0.1 and Rails 6.1.0 and had trouble installing Ruby, so I switched from rvm to rbenv. Since then, I have received countless warnings for rake commands.

Since then I get the following warnings when running rake:
`rake -T`

```
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Rake::VERSION
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::MAJOR
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of MAJOR was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::MINOR
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of MINOR was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::BUILD
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of BUILD was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::OTHER
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: previous definition of OTHER was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Version::NUMBERS
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/version.rb:8: warning: previous definition of NUMBERS was here
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/linked_list.rb:110: warning: already initialized constant Rake::LinkedList::EMPTY
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/linked_list.rb:110: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/scope.rb:41: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Scope::EMPTY
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/scope.rb:41: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::RUBY
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: previous definition of RUBY was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:108: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LN_SUPPORTED
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:108: warning: previous definition of LN_SUPPORTED was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileUtilsExt::DEFAULT
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:17: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::ARRAY_METHODS
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: previous definition of ARRAY_METHODS was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::MUST_DEFINE
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: previous definition of MUST_DEFINE was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: previous definition of MUST_NOT_DEFINE was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::SPECIAL_RETURN
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: previous definition of SPECIAL_RETURN was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DELEGATING_METHODS
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: previous definition of DELEGATING_METHODS was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:86: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::GLOB_PATTERN
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:86: warning: previous definition of GLOB_PATTERN was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:381: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:381: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:387: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileList::DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/file_list.rb:387: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/promise.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Promise::NOT_SET
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/promise.rb:12: warning: previous definition of NOT_SET was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:13: warning: already initialized constant Rake::CommandLineOptionError
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:13: warning: previous definition of CommandLineOptionError was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:41: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Application::DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:41: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_RAKEFILES was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:108: warning: already initialized constant Rake::EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:108: warning: previous definition of EMPTY_TASK_ARGS was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant Rake::InvocationChain::EMPTY
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:55: warning: previous definition of EMPTY was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/early_time.rb:21: warning: already initialized constant Rake::EARLY
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/early_time.rb:21: warning: previous definition of EARLY was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/late_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant Rake::LATE
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/late_time.rb:17: warning: previous definition of LATE was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SYS_KEYS
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:4: warning: previous definition of SYS_KEYS was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SYS_PATHS
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:5: warning: previous definition of SYS_PATHS was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESSED_PATHS
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:8: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESSED_PATHS was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESSED_PATHS_RE
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:12: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESSED_PATHS_RE was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:16: warning: already initialized constant Rake::Backtrace::SUPPRESS_PATTERN
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/backtrace.rb:16: warning: previous definition of SUPPRESS_PATTERN was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake.rb:70: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake.rb:70: warning: previous definition of FileList was here
/Users/chris/rails-project/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake.rb:71: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake.rb:71: warning: previous definition of RakeFileUtils was here
```

My GEM PATHS also seem to be in order:

```
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
     - /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/3.0.0
```

If I use `bundle exec rake` I don't get any warnings. Previously, however, this has only worked with me `rake`.

How can I get rid of these rake warnings?

Comment: Why is rake bundled in your vendor folder in the first place? Just delete it from there. That being said you should use `bundle exec` for commands to make sure they are executed in the context of your bundle (Gemfile)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just had to delete the .bundle file and deleted the vendor folder. Now that I have run bundle again, everything seems to be OK.